# How to correctly index an array?

Tags: r

Please download the file into your computer,and run :
http://freeuploadfiles.com/bb3cwypih2d2

```
data=read.table("path/to/file", sep="|",quote='',
       head=T,blank.lines.skip=T,as.is=T)
ddata=array(data,dim=c(nrow(data),ncol(data)))
ddata[1,1]
```

I want to extract the first element of the first column. The answer should be `AAC`.

How do I do that?

Comment: your array is called `ddata` not `ddate`.

Comment: isn't a problem of typing ? You've written `ddata` first and then `ddate`

Comment: In addition to what @mnel mentioned, do you mean `ddata[[1,1]][1]`?

Comment: It's because you haven't defined `ddate` in your code.

Comment: i am sorry for wrong typing,it is ddata[[1,1]][1],what is the reason?why ddata[[1]] get the same output as ddata[[1,1]],i can  not understand.

Comment: I am going to revert your last edit, since you have completely changed the original question.  If you have new questions, then post a new question.  But I suspect you will benefit from reading the excellent [R Manuals](http://cran.r-project.org/manuals.html), in particular [An introduction to R](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Some suggestions to clean your code and make life easier in the long term:

1. Work with the data in a `data.frame`, not an `array`.
2. Never refer to `TRUE` as `T`. `TRUE` is a reserved word that can never be redefined, whereas `T` can take any value, including `FALSE`
3. Use the `<-` symbol for assignment
4. Don't use abbreviate argument names. The arguement is `header`, not `head`. This might bite you

Arrays can only contain a single class of object. Thus converting your data to `array` will implicitly convert the `numeric` column to `character`, which surely is a bad thing.

You then index the data frame like this:

```
dat <- read.table("nasdaqlisted.txt", sep="|", quote='',
                   header=TRUE, blank.lines.skip=TRUE, as.is=TRUE)

dat$Symbol[1]
[1] "AAC"
```

The following alternative ways of indexing also return the same element:

```
dat[1, "Symbol"]
dat[1, 1]
dat[, 1][1]
dat[["Symbol"]][1]
```

---

If you **really** want to do the **foolish** thing and convert your data to an array, then use `matrix`:

```
mdat <- as.matrix(dat)
mdat[1, 1]
Symbol 
 "AAC"
```

Disclaimer: I only post this since you ask. Arrays and matrices are powerful and fast, but not appropriate for this data.

Comment: if i made them all  characters,why i can't get ddata[2,5]?

Comment: why i can't as.array(dat),
Error in dimnames<-.data.frame(*tmp*, value = list(n)) : invalid 'dimnames' given for data frame.
hwo can i do to change it into array with as.array()?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? A `matrix` **is** a two-dimensional `array`, so just work with the matrix. If you want to coerce it to an `array`, you have to supply the arguments `dim` in the same way as `array()`. See `?array` for help.

Comment: @Andrie, Great answer! Having started off using `<-` for assignment (not realizing that `=` was also allowed). I now wonder about the extra 2 keystrokes needed to write `<-` v. `=`. Is it really worth it? Thanks!

Comment: @Andrie I wouldn't advocate `<-` as much, looking at the original reasoning behind that operator in R, it doesn't apply these days. So I would say it is a matter of preferences. For me `<-` is especially useful when evaluated inline in another function call, like `f(tmp<-do(), tmp+5)`, and that cannot be achieved using `=` operator.